# Badges earned today. vs. UTC time

Tags: discussion, badges, timestamps, nice-answer

On Stack Overflow clicking on the dropdown by my name, it says I've earned a nice question badge today. it also says the UTC time is 16:15.

Clicking on the badge it says 19 hours ago, next to the question.

I was quite confused until I figured that it's when the question was posted, rather than when I got the badge.

Should this be changed to show when I got the badge instead of when I posted the question that received the badge?

Comment: The "Badges earned today" clearly don't follow the UTC clock, a one-time badge I earned yesterday is showing up today.

Comment: Hmm, guess my assumption that it goes by post time doesn't stand, maybe it's a rolling 24 hour window.

Comment: Seems entirely possible, I still have my investor badge from yesterday, it's been about 23 hours since I earned it.